# A divisibility property in a sequence with exponential terms

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, exact-sequence, totient-function, lifting-the-exponent

Given the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $a_n = \frac{{2 \cdot 2^{2^{n}} + 1}}{3}$, prove that $3^n \mid a_{3^n}$ for every $n \geq 1$.

I thought about using LTE 2 times for the numerator but I got stuck.

Comment: I wonder how you apply LTE, considering the 2 multiplying the 4.

Comment: Oh, you've edited the question and removed the three.

Comment: I feel I must warn you that your question is lacking [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/) and will be closed soon.

Comment: You are continuously changing the problem statement. What is the question exactly?

Comment: @DS -- the problem as stated earlier was incorrect. OP has resolved the problem in chat.

Comment: where exactly? @Sahaj

Comment: To the OP: This is a popular lemma in disguise. You will need $a \equiv b \pmod {m^n} \implies a^m \equiv b^m \pmod{m^{n+1}}$ along with LTE.

Comment: Upon more thinking, applying LTE twice should also have worked. If you show how you failed while using LTE, the question may be reopened.